# Leer un archivo XML y se carguen los datos en unos textbox y un checkedListBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms, xml

En un form_closing creo un archivo XML en donde lo escrito en los texrbox de un WinForms se guarda en el XML y funciona, lo que no me funciona es que al querer cargar los datos cuando abro el WinForms se carga todo menos el checkedListBox todo esto de la carga de datos lo manejo desde el LOAD y este el código que manejo pero no carga los datos del checkedListBox.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            string rutaArchivo = @"C:\downloads\Datos.xml";

            if (File.Exists(rutaArchivo))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Datos));

                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(rutaArchivo, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    Datos datos = (Datos)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);

                    servertextBox.Text = datos.server;
                    usertextBox.Text = datos.user;
                    passwordtextBox.Text = datos.password;
                    pathtextBox.Text = datos.path;
                    ProtocolotextBox.Text = datos.protocol;
                    AccoNametextBox.Text = datos.name;
                    AccouKeytextBox.Text = datos.key;
                    EndPointtextBox.Text = datos.endPoint;
                    ContainertextBox.Text = datos.container;
                    DBcheckedListBox.Text = datos.dataBase;



                }
            }
            else
            {
                servertextBox.Text = "";
                usertextBox.Text = "";
                passwordtextBox.Text = "";
                pathtextBox.Text = "";
                ProtocolotextBox.Text = "";
                AccoNametextBox.Text = "";
                AccouKeytextBox.Text = "";
                EndPointtextBox.Text = "";
                ContainertextBox.Text = "";
                DBcheckedListBox.Text = "";
                DBcheckedListBox.Items.Clear();
            }
        }
```